How can I debug IIS w3wp.exe in VSCode without running it as administrator?
I’m trying to debug an application hosted on IIS using VSCode, but I’m running into a permissions issue. When I open VSCode as a standard user, I cannot see the w3wp.exe process in the list of attachable processes. However, when I run VSCode as an administrator, I can see and attach to the process without any problems.
I want to avoid running VSCode with elevated privileges for security and convenience reasons. The only workaround I’ve found so far is to launch VSCode as an administrator, but I’d like to find a more permanent and non-admin solution.
Environment Details:
Windows 10/11
IIS 10.0
VSCode for debugging
Application hosted on IIS (not IIS Express)
Is there a way to configure IIS or VSCode to allow me to attach to the w3wp.exe process without running VSCode as an administrator? Any persistent changes or alternative debugging setups would be helpful.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Changed the IIS Application Pool Identity to my user account. Granted file system permissions to my user account for the website directory and applicationHost.config. Added my user account to the Debug Programs privilege in secpol.msc. None of these changes have allowed me to attach to the w3wp.exe process from VSCode without admin rights.

Do you strictly need to debug w3wp? ASP.Net Core runs as a separate console app, so you should be able to debug directly by launching it from VSCode


If security is your primary concern, then you shouldn't debug this application on this machine, but a dedicated Windows Server.
Anyway, you have to run VS Code as administrator if you directly attach a debugger from within to w3wp.exe, as that's required by Windows debugging infrastructure.

A workaround is to run another debugger as administrator (such as the ones mentioned in this article).
Then you might configure VS Code to launch a debugger to connect to that elevated debugger via remote debugging protocol, which is more often used to debug processes across machine boundaries
In this way, VS Code can run without administrator permissions.
